# How to run two different versions of same React-App simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `react-app` created with `create react app`. 
I have one branch which is ~1 month old, and a current branch. I want to run both branches simultaneously and make changes on the current branch. Is that possible?

What I tried

- copied the whole project folder
- Opened one terminal window
- checked out the old branch in the copied version
- `yarn start` on the default (`3000`) port
- then opening a new terminal window
- checked out the new version in the original version of the app
- changed the package.json to `"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"`.
- `yarn start`

But when I start the new version with `yarn start` on another port than `3000`, the app running on port `3000` compiles new and changes to the most current version....

Answer (score 0):

If running them simultaneously, you should change the port of one to be different than the other.

Have a look at their Github issues on how to do so:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1083

Comment: thats what i did. Opened one terminal window, checked out the old branch, and then `yarn start` on the default (`3000`) port. Then, opening a new terminal window, checked out the new version of the app and changed the `package.json` to  `"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"`. But when I start the new version with `yarn start` on another port than `3000`, the app running on port `3000` compiles new and changes to the most current version....

Comment: Webpack uses hot reloading, which reloads the project each time a file changes within the project directory. You will need to duplicate the project into a different folder, and then run one project on the default port, and change the duplicated project to the other port.

Comment: You may need to copy only your src files, and run `npm install` in the new directory. Not too sure after that Stophface, my apologies!